# Unable to hide address bar in Chrome browser for Android mobile devices in Sharepoint environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-2016

For quite some time I am trying to hide Chrome address bar in Mobile android devices by JavaScript. I am creating the application in Sharepoint. I tried many approaches like:

Ref:- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

1. `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`
2. `window.scrollTo(0,1);`
3. function toggleFullScreen() {   var doc = window.document;   var
       docEl = doc.documentElement;

   ```
     var requestFullScreen = docEl.requestFullscreen ||
   docEl.mozRequestFullScreen || docEl.webkitRequestFullScreen ||
   docEl.msRequestFullscreen;   var cancelFullScreen =
   doc.exitFullscreen || doc.mozCancelFullScreen ||
   doc.webkitExitFullscreen || doc.msExitFullscreen;

     if(!doc.fullscreenElement && !doc.mozFullScreenElement &&
   !doc.webkitFullscreenElement && !doc.msFullscreenElement) {
       requestFullScreen.call(docEl);   }   else {
       cancelFullScreen.call(doc);   } }
   ```

But all the approaches are failed.

Comment: I guess this is mostlikely to be CSS related

Comment: It might be. But usually on mobile devices, on scrolling down the address bar hides automatically and when you scroll up it display back automatically. In my case this default behavior of chrome is not working.